# Android MotionEvent : Transfer between views

Tags: android, touch-event, motionevent

I have two custom viewgroups that implements onTouchListener for motionevent.

I am using a framelayout to show them both. 
Second viewgroup is smaller in size than the first one. 
So the first one is in background and second one is foreground.

I want to drag item for second/smaller viewgroup to the background viewgroup.

Problem : When dragging the item to the background viewgroup `(i.e mAwesomePager)`, I want `ACTION_UP` to be triggered on the second viewgroup (smaller one) and `ACTION_MOVE` to be triggered on the first viewgroup, so basically the `touchEvent` is transferred from smaller viewgroup to the larger one in the background and the `MotionEvent` continues without the user has to take up the finger from the screen and then put it back again.

Here is some of the useful code :

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (mRectOut == true) {
        ev.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);
        mFrame.bringChildToFront(mAwesomePager);
        //mAwesomePager.setClickable(true);

        // Obtain MotionEvent object
        long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100;
        // List of meta states found here: developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#getMetaState()
        int metaState = 0;
        MotionEvent motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
                downTime,
                eventTime,
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                ev.getX(),
                ev.getY(),
                metaState
        );
        mAwesomePager.getChildAt(mAwesomePager.mLastDragged).dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    }
//some more code here

}
```

I am trying to simulate touch off in the foreground view by this `ev.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);` , now I want the background view to take control over the touch while the touch is holding the dragged image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing this
`mAwesomePager.getChildAt(mAwesomePager.mLastDragged).dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);`

to this

`return mAwesomePager.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);`

eventually did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the documentation of the `onTouchEvent()` method, more specifically its return parameter:

> Returns
>   **True** if the event was handled, **false** otherwise.

If you want your events to be passed to you background view, you need to make sure that when a `ACTION_UP` happens, the method returns false so Android knows the motion event was not consumed yet and should be relayed to the next view in the hierarchy.

Here's a basic snippet of what to do:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        // handle ACTION_UP with the foreground view
        return false; // event will be sent to the background view
    } else {
        // handle ACTION_MOVE with the foreground view
        return true; // event will stop here
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that your background view will also need to implement the touch listener on its turn for this to happen.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying to simulate touch off in the foreground view by this `ev.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);` , now I want the background view to take control over the touch while the touch is holding the dragged image. `return false` terminates touch events for both the views.

Comment: Assuming you keep returning true, does the motionEvent you're creating get dispatched to the background view?